# Как копировать строку в таблице в Delphi в базе access

Tags: access, ado, delphi

есть таблица 'Jornal'

```
 id | name | .....| datetime
 1  | имя  | .....| 10.10.10
```

задача:
выделить одну запись в DBgrid нажать на кнопку и в базе появилась скопированная строка и в DBgrid тоже с теми же значениями как в выделенной строке

Comment: а id? тот же?

Comment: нет, id меняеться

Answer (score 1):

Но тут уже надо просто подумать и додуматься до нехитрых действий:

```
...
var
name:string;
dt:TDateTime;
...
begin
name:=Table1.Fields.FieldByName('name').AsString;   // получаем данные
dt:=Table1.Fields.FieldByName('datetime').AsDateTime;

Table1.Insert;                             // вставляем их 
Table1.FieldByName('name').AsString:=name;
Table1.FieldByName('datetime'):=dt;
Table1.Post;
```

Если поле 'ID' имеет атрибут  AUTO_INCREMENT, то оно само о себе позаботится.
Все остальные поля таблицы не должны иметь атрибута UNIQUE( уникальность ), иначе это приведет к ошибке.